# Highlight the searched keywords in Elastic Search giving an error

Tags: elasticsearch

Working on Elastic Search 6.4.2. Trying to implement the highlighting the keywords. When I try to run the below query I am getting unsupported error. Any way to use the highlight in this query.
**Query:**

```
{
       "query":{
          "bool":{
             "must":{
                "query_string":{
                   "query":"test"
                }
             },
             "filter":{
                "term":{
                   "college":"engineering"
                }
             },
             "highlight":{
                "fields":{
                   "*":{

                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

**Error:**

```
"[bool] query does not support [highlight]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The highlight parameter need to be at the same level as the query, not inside.